# ActiveScaffold - changing default name of associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activescaffold

My model `"combobox" has_many "comboboxselects"`, and `"comboboxselects" belongs_to "combobox"`. Activescaffold of "comboboxes" displays data in comboboxselects-column like `"#<Comboboxselect:0x472d25c>"`. How to make display the "answer" column from table "comboxselects"?

Models:

```
class Combobox < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comboboxselects
end

class Comboboxselect < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :combobox
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "comboboxes", :force => true do |t|
   t.string   "question"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "comboboxselects", :force => true do |t|
   t.integer  "combobox_id"
   t.string   "answer"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Output:

```
class ComboboxesController < ApplicationController
 active_scaffold :combobox do |config|
   config.list.columns = [:id, :question]
   config.columns = [:question, :comboboxselects]
 end
end

class ComboboxselectsController < ApplicationController
 active_scaffold :comboboxselect  do |config|
   config.list.columns = [:id, :combobox, :answer]
   config.columns = [:answer]
 end
end
```

Comment: model files for those two models, and their schemas, please.

Comment: I have added it, you may see it now. Thank you for interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, all fields referenced in config.list.columns have to be included in config.columns (any explicitly-defined config.*.columns fields must be subsets of config.columns).

Then, in each model that does not already have a name or title field or method, you have to declare this custom method:

```
class Comboboxselect < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :combobox
 def to_label
  "#{answer}" 
 end
end
```

See ActiveScaffold documentation: [Describing Records: to_label](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Describing-Records:-to_label)

Answer (score 0):

When you say displays I assume you mean in a view? Can you post the code your running to get that output.

Looks to me like you just have Comboboxselect object, have you tried adding `.answer` to it to access the attribute you want?

Comment: Yes, in an activescaffold default view. I have added the activescaffold default loading config.

Hm.. You are right, and I don't now how to output the :answer.